# Testing a download file with symfony2

Tags: symfony, phpunit

Can you please help me on how to test a download file in symfony2?
There are my source code :

Controller.php

```
public function downloadAction($picture_id) 
{

    $fichier= $this->uploadDir.$picture_id; 
    if (($fichier != "") && (file_exists($fichier))) {
        $content = file_get_contents($fichier);

        $response = new Response();
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream');
        $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment;filename="'.$picture_id);

        $response->setContent($content);

        return $response;
    }
    else return new Response(json_encode(array("response_code" => "ko")));  


}
```

ControllerTest.php

```
public function testdownload()
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible;)");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "path/img.jpg");
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
}
```

The issue is that how can I test that the download has been successful,or which assertion could I use to do my functionnal test?

Comment: I recommend you to see this http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/testing.html#functional-tests

Comment: thank you,I have already found the solution.Thank you very much

Comment: @little if you already have found the solution, then why the hell you not sharing with us... ?

Answer (score 3):

Asked 5 years ago, but maybe someone will find this useful (functional test):

```
$client = static::createClient();
$client->request('GET', '/path/img.jpg');

$this->assertEquals(true, $client->getResponse()->isOk());
$binaryData = $client->getInternalResponse()->getContent()
```

The problem is that `$client->getResponse()->getContent()` returns empty string when there's binary data.

Tested with Symfony 4.2.