# Download file functional test on Symfony2

Tags: symfony, curl, phpunit

With symfony2, how to test (functional test) that the file has been downloaded well on the client's side? I have tried the following code but something is wrong.

My controller:

```php
public function downloadAction($picture_id) 
{

    $fichier= $this->uploadDir.$picture_id; 
    if (($fichier != "") && (file_exists($fichier))) {
        $content = file_get_contents($fichier);

        $response = new Response();
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream');
        $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment;filename="'.$picture_id);

        $response->setContent($content);

        return $response;
    }
}
```

Test code:

```php
public function testupload()
{

        $ch = curl_init();
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
                //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: image/jpeg"));
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible;)");
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "Path_to _myFile/file.png");
                //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);        
                $response = curl_exec($ch);

                //$json_response = json_decode($response);

                print "resp -> ".$response->headers;


}
```

Finally, the response by phpunit:

> 1) Application\MediaBundle\Tests\Controller\PictureControllerCopyTest::testupload
>   Trying to get property of non-object
>
> /var/www/symfony/ws1/src/Application/MediaBundle/Tests/Controller/PictureControllerCopyTest.php:28
>
> FAILURES!
>   Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Errors: 1.

Comment: [Exact dupe](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15810352/1607098) - If you have any addition, please edit your previous post. FYI, [curl_exec](http://php.net/curl_exec) does not return a `Response` object.

Answer (score 0):

Write a functional test instead of using curl. The advantage is you won't need a web server to run your test, since the kernel would be called directly (it's faster than going through a web server).

Read on functional tests in the docs: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/testing.html#functional-tests